# Nativescript-ui-charts: PointLabelStyle of PieSeries remove borders (stroke)

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I'm trying to show a pie chart with their values inside the chart but when I set showLabels="true" it also adds a white box around the value.

I'd like to remove these boxes but the strokeColor and strokeWidth properties doesn't seem to work. Is there any workaround for this?

```html
<RadPieChart height="300" allowAnimation="true" row="0">
    <PieSeries  tkPieSeries expandRadius="0.5" outerRadiusFactor="0.7" [items]="pieSource" valueProperty="Amount" showLabels="true">
        <PointLabelStyle tkPieLabelStyle strokeColor="cyan" strokeWidth="3" fillColor="red" textSize="8"></PointLabelStyle>
    </PieSeries>
</RadPieChart>
```

Comment: Open an issue request on their github.  I'd love to find an answer to this as well.